# Determining Folder Attribute in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file in which I need to determine whether or not a particular folder on my hard drive is a Hidden folder.  The batch file will then proceed depending on the answer.

I've studied the responses to some similar questions here but I'm still not getting it.  Any help with this part of my batch file appreciated.

Note: It's the same folder all the time but the System attribute changes from time to time.

Thanks!

Comment: You got an answer on Usenet too.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `attrib` command is in the format 'A_*SHR*_I', so we will test if the fifth character in output is an `H` to determine if the folder is hidden

```
attrib "c:\Myfolder" | findstr /r /c:".  .H" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Folder is NOT HIDDEN
) else (
    echo Folder IS HIDDEN
)
```

This is the behaviour in a Windows 7 Spanish installation. Try on your systems and adapt as needed.